# How can I switch whitespace-mode enabled/disabled by key?

Tags: key-bindings, whitespace, whitespace-mode

```el
(defun switch-whitespace-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (whitespace-mode)
)

(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'switch-whitespace-mode)
```

Through the above configuration，I failed.

Comment: Please include code as a code block (indented by 4 spaces). A <!-- language: lang-el -->  line above the block will provide fontification.

Comment: It‘s my first time to ask question. And I will adopt it next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a set of conventions for minor modes documented in the docstring of `define-minor-mode`:

> The defined mode command takes one optional (prefix) argument.
>   Interactively with no prefix argument, it toggles the mode.
>   A prefix argument enables the mode if the argument is positive,
>   and disables it otherwise.
>
> When called from Lisp, the mode command toggles the mode if the
>   argument is `toggle', disables the mode if the argument is a
>   non-positive integer, and enables the mode otherwise (including
>   if the argument is omitted or nil or a positive integer).

In other words, `M-x whitespace-mode` will toggle the state of the mode, `(whitespace-mode)` won't.  Use `(whitespace-mode 'toggle)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`whitespace-mode` is already an interactive function and, if *called* interactively, toggles the mode.

So the simplest answer to your question is:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'whitespace-mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

`C-h f whitespace-mode` tells you what your problem is:

> whitespace-mode is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
>   `whitespace.el`.
>
> **`(whitespace-mode &optional ARG)`**
>
> Toggle whitespace visualization (Whitespace mode).
>
> With a prefix argument ARG, enable Whitespace mode if ARG is
>   positive, and disable it otherwise.  **If called from Lisp, enable
>   the mode if ARG is omitted or nil.**
>
> See also `whitespace-style`, `whitespace-newline` and
>   `whitespace-display-mappings`.

The sentence I've put in **bold** tells you that with no argument the mode is *enabled*. In other words: `(whitespace-mode)` always enables the mode.

The doc string does *not* tell you, unfortunately, how to *toggle the mode using Lisp*.  This is a bug, IMO (I've filed Emacs [bug #24413](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24413) for this).  The `define-minor-mode` call that defines this mode explicitly provides a doc string that is deficient in this way.  If it had simply relied on the generic doc string provided by `define-minor-mode` then you would have seen this:

> Toggle whitespace-mode on or off.
>
> With a prefix argument ARG, enable Whitespace mode if ARG is
>   positive, and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable
>   the mode if ARG is omitted or nil, **and toggle it if ARG is `toggle`**.

@wasamasa's answer -- consult the doc of `define-minor-mode` -- provides this missing information: Use `(whitespace-mode 'toggle)`. (And it lets you know that the same holds for other minor modes defined using `define-minor-mode`.)

Comment: After reading your enthusiastic explanation, I know more clearly. Thanks!